# Is it possible to test Sentry.ErrorBoundary rendering in jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, sentry

I've just implemented the Sentry.ErrorBoundary component and I was wondering if it was possible to test the rendering of it. For example:

```
<Sentry.ErrorBoundary>
    <FailComponent />
  </Sentry.ErrorBoundary>
```

or

```
<Sentry.ErrorBoundary>
    <SuccessComponent />
  </Sentry.ErrorBoundary>
```

Answer (score 0):

I' d suggest another approach on this, which is to work with a custom `ErrorBoundary` HO-component, as `react` doc (https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) and catch the error into the `componentDidCatch()` function, instead.

In this way you can more easily test your hoc component.

The error boundary component will be like so:

```
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/browser';

type State = {
  hasError?: boolean,
  eventId?: string,
  error: null | Error,
  errorInfo?: null | {componentStack: string},
};

type Props = {
  children: any,
}

class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error: Error, errorInfo: any) {
    const { children } = this.props;

    // Configure what data you want to update, whenever an error happens.
    // Here, i update the breadcrumbs 
    Sentry.addBreadcrumb({
      type: Sentry.Severity.Error,
      category: 'component',
      message: children.props.name || 'n/a',
      level: Sentry.Severity.Error,
    });

    // Here, i set tag and some extra infos, plus the exception.

    Sentry.configureScope((scope: any) => {
      scope.setTag('component', children.props.name || 'n/a');
      scope.setExtra('component info', error);
      scope.setExtras(errorInfo);
      Sentry.captureException(error, scope);
      this.setState({
        error,
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      error,
    } = this.state;

    const {
      children,
    } = this.props;

    // In case of an error, the fallback UI kicks in.
    if (error) {
      // custom fallback UI
      // We return an empty component with 'data-attr'
      //  with the failing component name (for debug purposes)
      return (
        <>
          <div data-attr={children.props.name} />
        </>
      );
    }

    return children;
  }
}

export default ErrorBoundary;
```

After the above, you can use the errorboundary hoc like so:

```
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <Mycomponent />
      </ErrorBoundary>
```

**If an error happens into `<Mycomponent />`, the `<ErrorBoundary />` will render, with the UI that you set**

You can test it as you test your rest components, like check if it has been rendered.
Hope this helps.